# How to do binding of a grid using mvvm to render UI elemnts on it

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, silverlight, mvvm

I am a c# Silverlight beginner and i am using silverlight5 with MVVM approach.

What i have to do ? 
I have created a xaml suppose  this :

```
<UserControl x:Class="DEV_CENTER.TabControlStuff.UIeLementRender"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now i want to bind this grid to a viewModel class which will render a **grid containing combobox** on it . How to do that ?

I tried adding `"{Binding UIElements}"` by changing grid like this

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" {Binding UIElements}>
```

which is ofcourse not supported.

So how to bind this grid to render UIElemnts on it (combo box) using MVVm approach ?

**EDIT :** Situation is that i have a grid which already contain a Combobox (obtained dynamically using c# code) and that grid i want to render on a grid(this grid is default grid obtained on creating xaml)(by binding using MVVM i have to render the previously obtained grid (using c# ,containign combobox) by binding it to this xaml degault created grid using MVVM by doing something like `{Binding  AlreadComboContainingGrig}`).

Whereas my ViewModel class which will be binded will look like this :

```
 public class uiElementRendererViewModel : GenericViewModel
    {

        private Grid alreadComboContainingGrig;
        public Grid AlreadComboContainingGrig
        {
            get { return alreadComboContainingGrig; }
            set { alreadComboContainingGrig= value; OnPropertyChanged("AlreadComboContainingGrig"); }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible ? If not then could u please tell me any alternative ?Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way is to have container element in outer Grid, such as ContentController or Frame as placeholder, and bind it's content to inner Grid.
Something like this in XAML:

```
<Grid Name="GlobalGrid">
   <ContentControl Name="ComboGridPlaceholder" Content = "{Binding alreadComboContainingGrig}"/>
</Grid>
```

The only thing remains is not to forget setting correct DataContext for ComboGridPlaceholder.

Comment: situation is i have a grid which already contain a Combobox (obtained dynamically using c# code) and that grid i want to render on a grid (by binding using MVVM). Is it possible ? If not then could u please tell me any alternative ?Thanks .

Comment: Than you can use Frame (or Border) UI element as placeholder for your obtained grid. Frame's property Content and Border's Child can be binded. Though I didn't tested it.

Comment: do you think  ContentControl willbe Ok to bind so as to render Grid on it ?

Comment: Yes. I've forgot about it, this would perfectly suite your needs.

Comment: @Ingwart so now change your answer so that i would give you some points by marrking it